# Angular JS and Bootstrap - Setting multiple sub menus within submenus

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Let me start by saying I am very much in the beginning stages of learning to use Angular. I've done multiple searches, and seen multiple examples of setting up a menu with sub menus, but have found none for me to look at that have sub menus within sub menus.

I'm also, as you may have noticed, not very good at writing a question either. Let me continue with the code and a fiddle for an example. Hopefully someone can explain why this isn't working and where my logic has gone awry.

**JavaScript**

```
var App = angular.module("rcfdto",[]);
App.controller("menuController", ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.locs = [

                            {

                                            name: "Menu Option #1",

                                            link: "#OP1",

                                            id: "Option1",

                                            submenu: null

                            },

                            {

                                            name: "Menu Option #2",

                                            link: "#OP2",

                                            id: "Option2",

                                            submenu: [

                                                            {

                                                                            name: "Submenu Option 1",

                                                                            link: "#SOP1",

                                                                            id: "SubOption1",

                                                                            subsubmenu: null

                                                            },

                                                            {

                                                                            name: "Submenu Option 2",

                                                                            link: "#SOP2",

                                                                            id: "SubOption2",

                                                                            subsubmenu: null

                                                            },

                                                            {

                                                                            name: "Submenu Option 3",

                                                                            link: "#SOP3",

                                                                            id: "SubmenuOption3",

                                                                            subsubmenu: [

                                                                                            {

                                                                                                            name: "SubSubMenu Option 1",

                                                                                                            link: "#SSOP1",

                                                                                                            id: "SubSubmenuOption1"

                                                                                            },

                                                                                            {

                                                                                                            name: "SubSubMenu Option 2",

                                                                                                            link: "#SSOP2",

                                                                                                            id: "SubSubmenuOption2"

                                                                                            }

                                                                            ]

                                                            }

                                            ]

                            },

                            {

                                            name: "Menu Option #3",

                                            link: "#OP3",

                                            id: "Option3",

                                            submenu: [

                                                            {

                                                                            name: "Submenu Option 4",

                                                                            link: "#SOP4",

                                                                            id: "SubmenuOption4",

                                                                            subsubmenu: [

                                                                                            {

                                                                                                            name: "SubSubMenu Option 3",

                                                                                                            link: "#SSOP3",

                                                                                                            id: "SubSubmenuOption3"

                                                                                            }

                                                                            ]

                                                            },

                                                            {

                                                                            name: "Submenu Option 5",

                                                                            link: "#SOP5",

                                                                            id: "SubmenuOption5",

                                                                            submenu: null

                                                            }

                                            ]

                            }

];
```

}]);

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="rcfdto">

<div class="menu container" ng-controller="menuController">

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

  <li ng-repeat="loc in locs" ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu' : loc.submenu && loc.submenu.length}">

    <a href="{{loc.link}}" id="{{loc.id}}">{{loc.name}}</a>

      <ul ng-if="loc.submenu && loc.submenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">

        <li ng-repeat="subloc in loc.submenu">

          <a href="{{subloc.link}}" id="{{subloc.id}}">{{subloc.name}}</a>

            <ul ng-if="subloc.subsubmenu && subloc.subsubmenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">

              <li ng-repeat="subsubloc in subloc.subsubmenu">

                <a href="{{subsubloc.link}}" id="{{subsubloc.id}}">{{subsubloc.name}}</a>

              </li>

            </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {

            position:relative;

}

.menu > .dropdown-menu {

            position:static;

            display:block;

}
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdvt6hhw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the correct class on your menus.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <li ng-repeat="loc in locs" ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu' : loc.submenu && loc.submenu.length}">
    <a href="{{loc.link}}" id="{{loc.id}}">{{loc.name}}</a>
      <ul ng-if="loc.submenu && loc.submenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">

<!-- ng-class added in this line -->
            <li ng-repeat="subloc in loc.submenu" ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu' : subloc.subsubmenu && subloc.subsubmenu.length}">
              <a href="{{subloc.link}}" id="{{subloc.id}}">{{subloc.name}}</a>
                <ul ng-if="subloc.subsubmenu && subloc.subsubmenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li ng-repeat="subsubloc in subloc.subsubmenu">
                    <a href="{{subsubloc.link}}" id="{{subsubloc.id}}">{{subsubloc.name}}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I recommend to rename "subsubmenu" to just "submenu" and extract directives out of this messy structure.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you for your assistance, I'm still figuring this stuff out and trying to make head or tails of it, and using this as a project to learn from. I will also make the other changes. Thank you again